# Sql Query NOT IN in visual basic

Tags: sql

I have this SQL update statement which is written in VB code.

```
  MyDatabase.Execute "Update DebtorCreditCardDetails set AccountID = " & NewDriver.Number & " where AccountID = " & Me.Number & " and DebtorCreditCardID not in (select id from [DebtorCreditCards] where [number] = " & NewDriver.Number & " and IsActive = 0)"
```

In this statement the NOT IN part of query is not working. Since i have no idea of how to write it in VB. please help me with correction of this statement.

Comment: This has got nothing to do with VB. The VB is simply being used to insert values into the SQL code. The SQL code is still the SQL code. If you have issues with SQL code then you should go to your database management software first and work on the SQL there. Once you have it working, you can copy it into your application code and modify as required. Apart from that you seem to have posted VB6, VBA or VBScript code rather than VB.NET

Comment: As with EVERY question on this site, you can't just post some code and say that it's not working. You need to provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation of the problem, as specific in the Help Center. We shouldn't have work out what you're trying to do from code that doesn't do it. You should already know by now but I suggest that you spend some time in the Help Center to learn how to write a good question.

Answer (score 0):

First, I strongly encourage you to use *parameters* rather than munging query strings with literal values.  The following uses a parameter placeholder.

Second, I also strongly discourage using `NOT IN` with a subquery.  It never returns "true" if even one row in the subquery returns a `NULL` value.

Instead, use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
Update DebtorCreditCardDetails
    set AccountID = ?
    where AccountID = ? and
          not exists (select 1 
                      from DebtorCreditCards dcc
                      where DebtorCreditCardDetails.DebtorCreditCardID = dcc.id and
                            dcc.number = ? and 
                            dcc.IsActive = 0
                     );
```